# Generic stack in C

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, pointers

I tried to implement a generic stack in C using `void` pointers and tried to keep it as simple as possible by delegating all responsibility to the caller of the functions and avoiding more sophisticated approaches.

**stack.h**

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <stdbool.h>

struct Stack {
    void *data;
    struct Stack *next;
};

/*
 * We declare a pointer to a Stack structure thereby making use of incomplete
 * types. Clients that pull in stack.h will be able to declare variables of type
 * pstack which are pointers to pointers to Stack structures.
 * */
typedef struct Stack *pstack;

bool is_empty(pstack *s);
void make_empty(pstack *s);
void push(struct Stack **s, void *new_num);
void *pop(pstack *s);

#endif /* STACK_H */
```

**stack.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

bool is_empty(pstack *s) { return !s; }

void make_empty(pstack *s)
{
    if (!is_empty(s))
        pop(s);
}

void *pop(pstack *s)
{
    struct Stack *tmp;
    void *i;

    if (is_empty(s))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    tmp = *s;
    i = (*s)->data;
    *s = (*s)->next;
    free(tmp);
    return i;
}

void push(struct Stack **s, void *new_num)
{
    struct Stack *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    if (!new_node)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    new_node->data = new_num;
    new_node->next = *s;
    *s = new_node;
}
```

**stackclient.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

int main(void)
{
    pstack s1;
    void *n;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 2;

    push(&s1, &i);
    push(&s1, &j);

    n = pop(&s1);
    printf("Popped %d from s1\n", *((int *)n));
    n = pop(&s1);
    printf("Popped %d from s1\n", *((int *)n));

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: About naming convention: consider naming your function `stack_*` instead.  Since this is C and there is no namespace this will reduce the chance of functions' names clash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Use all required `#include`s

The `stack.c` file has `#include <stdio.h>` but it appears to me that no functions from it are needed.  On the other hand, it uses the `bool` from `stdbool.h` but doesn't include it directly.  One might argue (correctly!) that because it include `stack.h` that it's included indirectly, but I'd advocate that it's also in the implementation file so that it's obvious that the `bool` used there is the `stdbool.h` version.

### Use `const` where practical

The `is_empty` function does not alter the stack, so that argument should express that notion by using the `const` keyword:

```
bool is_empty(const pstack *s) { return !s; }
```

### Combine typedef and structure declaration

It's a common C idiom to combine the typedef and the stack declaration.

```
typedef struct Stack {
    void *data;
    struct Stack *next;
} *pstack;
```

This keeps them together which helps the reader of the code.

### Don't misuse `exit`

The final statement in main currently is:

```
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

However, code to return `EXIT_SUCCESS` is automatically generated if the code reaches the end of `main` so this is not needed.  Also, it may be more appropriate to return `NULL` instead of aborting the program with `exit` if too many `pop` operations are requested.

### Consider object ownership

The stack only stores pointers, but does not "own" the objects to which those pointers point.  This means that if you push pointers to stack objects with `auto` scope, the stack will contain invalid pointers if the underlying items go out of scope.  An alternative would be to create a copy of the object and allow the `stack` to own them.

### Don't rely on values not set

The `pstack` relies on the value being 0, (in `is_empty` and `make_empty`) but does not explicity set it to that (r any) value.  If your code checks for a specific value, it should also set it.

Comment: Thanks! Where should I set the value to 0? Do you mean when I declare `pstack s1` in `main()` by setting `s1 = NULL` at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, set `s1 = NULL` at the beginning and also change to `bool is_empty(pstack *s) { return s != NULL; }`

Comment: What I basically did was to implement a `create()` and `destroy()` function: `pstack create(void) {pstack s = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack)); if (!s) {exit(EXIT_FAILURE)}; s->next = NULL; return s;}` and `void destroy(pstack s) {free(s);};`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Combine typedef and structure declaration" this is bad advise and suggests that you don't know the meaning of opaque type. I would remove this part of your otherwise good answer, as it is incorrect in the context of creating an opaque type ADT. "Consider object ownership" is related to this: the ADT allocates the objects, since it is impossible for the caller to do so: it cannot create an instance of an incomplete type!

Comment: @Lundin: whether the `typedef` and `struct` declaration are on the same line or two different ones has no bearing on whether it's an opaque type or not.

Comment: @Edward Of course it does, there must be one declaration of incomplete type visible to the caller and the struct definition of that type, which is not visible to the caller. Why would you have the typedef at the struct definition rather than at the incomplete type declaration? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lundin: when they're both in the same file, as in this program, it makes no difference.  You seem to assume that an opaque type was a design goal. It's one way to implement, but not the only way or neccesarily the best way.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
 * We declare a pointer to a Stack structure thereby making use of incomplete
 * types. Clients that pull in stack.h will be able to declare variables of type
 * pstack which are pointers to pointers to Stack structures.
 * */
```

Few problems here. First, a variable of type `pstack` is just a pointer to `Stack` structure, not *pointer to pointer to* as the comment claims. Second, you do not use incomplete type as intended: the client still sees the implementation of `struct Stack`, and any change in implementation would result in client code being recompiled for no reason. A standard way to deal with it is to leave

```
typedef struct Stack stack;
```

in the header file `stack.h`, and declare

```
struct Stack {
    ...
};
```

in the implementation file `stack.c`.

Comment: Cheers. I know that `pstack` is not a pointer to a pointer but when I declare in `stack.c` with `pstack s1` then `s1` will be a pointer to a `pstack` pointer would it not?

Comment: A declaration `pstack s1;` declares a pointer to `struct Stack`. To get a pointer to a `pstack` pointer one would declare `pstack ** s`.

Comment: Then I'm confused as to why I need to pass `&s1` to my functions instead of just `s1`. (That confused me before. An example is my `push()` function which I declared without the `typedef` by using `void push(struct Stack **s, int new_num)`.)

Comment: Your functions must modify the argument (the top of stack changes). In C the only way to modify an argument is to pass a pointer to it.

Comment: Ah, I got it.. The functions expect a pointer to a pointer but `pstack` is just a pointer. Hence I need to pass the address of the `pstack` pointer in order to get a pointer to a pointer in order to be able to modify the argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a working program, you have several bugs. Also, the program design is not the correct way to implement opaque type.

**Program design**

- Opaque type should not be typedef:ed to a pointer type. In general, it is very bad practice to hide pointers behind typedefs because it severely reduces readability. Instead, typedef the opaque type as an incomplete struct. `typedef struct stack_t stack_t;`
- Opaque type means that the struct definition should *not* be visible to the caller, so it shouldn't be in the "public" header file! But rather in the "private" c file.
- True opaque type means that the ADT is responsible for allocating all objects, because the caller can't create an object of incomplete type. Therefore you need one create() function and one delete() function which create/delete objects of type `stack_t`.
- You probably want to keep track of the size of the data somehow, for example with a data size member in the struct.
- `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` in the middle of a function is very questionable practice. Instead, you should implement your functions with a returned error code and let the caller worry about which action to take.

**Bugs**

- make_empty() doesn't empty the stack, as one may think by reading its name. The `if(!is_empty(s))` needs to be `while (!is_empty(s))`.
- Which leads to the next bug, `pop` doesn't modify the pointer (it can't), so an empty pointer is never set to NULL anywhere.
- Somewhere the first/last next pointer must be set to NULL.

**Stylistic details**

- Minor issue: since struct tags and typedefs reside in different scopes (namespaces), you can use the same name for the struct tag and the typedef. Then the code turns less confusing to read.
- It is usually convention to name types `stack_t`. Depends on coding style. So in the h file you should have something like `typedef struct stack_t stack_t;`
- Read up on *const correctness*. Functions that don't modify a pointed-to object should have the pointer declared as pointer-to-const.
- Since the h file in the public documentation of what a c file does, it is best to put all `#include` in the h file, to show which dependencies your module has on other libraries.
- Do not use the boolean logic not `!` operator to compare integers or pointers, it should only be used for boolean logic. Instead, checks against null for a pointer should be made explicit, `s == NULL`.
- Always use braces `{ }` (aka "compound statements") after every single `if` or loop. People who don't do this *will* write bugs, sooner or later. See Apple's "goto fail" bug as one perfect example. I don't think the person who wrote that billion dollar bug was a rookie, but rather an arrogant veteran insisting on not using braces, for no good reason.
- Always `return` from main() even though C allows the return statement to safely be omitted.

Comment: Why do you assume that an opaque type was a design goal?

Comment: This would be a gret answer if you went a bit more into the *why?*, especially in the style part were you make some controversial claims (return from main and dont' use `!`) without backing them up.

Comment: @Edward Because that's how you properly design C programs with private encapsulation. Why would I assume that the OP doesn't want a proper program design?

Comment: @jacwah Because `!` is a boolean operator and for the sake of readability it should only be used on expressions that are "effectively boolean". Good C programmers program as if C had a real, type safe boolean type. Don't mix up booleans with integers or pointers. In any other programming language such things wouldn't even compile. References MISRA-C:2004, MISRA-C:2012 etc.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks. Though MISRA states that `!x` as advisory (Rule 13.2) and not required and only in the interest of clarity. It is such a common `C` idiom that I do not necessarily see a problem with this unless required by a specific coding style.

Comment: @brauner There's a lot of sloppy, ugly and incorrect things that are common practice among C programmers...

Comment: @Lundin, fair point!